# Submitting concurrent task via QFuture from GUI thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface, qfuture

In order to avoid computations in GUI thread on button click I'm trying to run it in separate thread.

As soon as I want to have ability to monitor progress my code is based on [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-progressdialog-main-cpp.html) source.

So, my code is:

```
futureWatcher.setFuture(QtConcurrent::mapped(library_pool.cbegin(), library_pool.cend(), util->loadFilesInLibrary(library_pool)));

futureWatcher.waitForFinished();

table = QFuture::result();
```

Which is quite similar to the given sorce from qt docs, but it gives corresponding errors:

```
C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'QFuture<QtPrivate::MapResultType<void,MapFunctor>::ResultType> QtConcurrent::mapped(Iterator,Iterator,MapFunctor)'
C2780: 'QFuture<QtPrivate::MapResultType<void,MapFunctor>::ResultType> QtConcurrent::mapped(const Sequence &,MapFunctor)': expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
C2955: 'QFuture': use of class template requires template argument list
'QFuture<T>::result': illegal call of non-static member function
```

So, how do I properly populate worker thread(s) with function from non-gui class in `button_clicked` slot without making GUI hand?

**UPD**

Well, I've succeeded with compiling code for now and this is how it works:

```
futureWatcher.setFuture(QtConcurrent::run(&this->util, &Utils::loadFilesInLibrary, library_pool.at(0)));

futureWatcher.waitForFinished();

library_pool = future.result();
```

But button click still results to error in runtime:
[image: runtime error]

My function which I'm trying to run generates no widgets, so the reason of this message is unclear.

I've read couple questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469768/widgets-must-be-created-in-the-gui-thread-error-how-to-correct-the-code?rq=1)) where all the code stated to work but it resides only in `main()` which is far from my needs. So, again, how do I start it from GUI thread?

Answer (score 0):

You can use non-static members with QtConcurrent methods with the help of a wrapper. There is more discussion about it at [Qt's Forums](https://forum.qt.io/topic/26485/using-qtconcurrent-map-with-pointer-to-non-static-member-function). [Here's another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961818/no-matching-function-for-call-to-object-mapit) asking about how to use the wrapper.

```
struct AddWrapper {
  Utils *utils = nullptr;
  typedef MyType result_type;

  AddWrapper(Util *u): instance(u) {};
  MyType operator()(const MyType &t) const {
    return instance->longMethod(t);
  }
}

Utils *foo = new Utils();
AddWrapper wrapper(foo);
QFuture<MyType> results = QtConcurrent::mapped(myList, wrapper);
```